# Error in execution of query in java class

Tags: java, sql

hi am not to execute the following query. it works fine in sql developer but doesnt work in my java class

```
    query = new StringBuilder().append("select SUBSTR(attrib,2) as DEF,DECODE(parent_id,null,null,'C'||parent_id) as xyz,'C'||attribute_id as lmn,decode(parent_id,null,'C'||(to_char(attribute_id)),'C'||parent_id||'/'||'C'||attribute_id) as abc from (select ATTRIBUTE_NAME,SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ATTRIBUTE_NAME, '/') as attrib, TREESTRUCT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME,parent_id,attribute_id from MY_TABLE where TREESTRUCT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = 'xyz' start with attribute_level =1 connect by prior attribute_id = parent_id);").toString();

Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
System.out.println("After connection");
ResultSet rs =  stmt.executeQuery(query);
System.out.println("After ececute");
```

query is not executed. goes to the exception block. what should i do to execute this query in my java class

Comment: what exception are you getting..show in detail

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Whenever you ask a question, please think about what information someone trying to help you is going to want to know about. In this case we really, really need to see the exception. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints (Additionally, why are you using a `StringBuilder`? You're just creating it, appending a single string, and then calling `toString`. That's an obscure way of writing `String query = "select ...";`)

Comment: Am getting  ORA-00911: invalid character exception

Comment: Try removing the semicolon at the end of your query.